# crawler stopped when running in the background in ubuntu

Tags: python, web-crawler

I made a simple crawler using python that has infinite loop so it can't be stop. 
With random delay 17 ~ 30, this crawler crawl same one page and find 'href' links that is updated periodically and store to Mysql.
I used Ubuntu server.
Because i used Linux command that

```
$ nohup python crawer.py &
```

so this crawler was running in Ubuntu server background. 
and it has ran about 4 hours i think.
but suddenly crawler stopped.
and next day i try again. and it works well!
what is the problem? is this about web page's block? or does nohup command has limit time????
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `nohup` will do what it's designed to to. That is:

> ```
>  The nohup utility invokes utility with its arguments and at this time
>  sets the signal SIGHUP to be ignored.  If the standard output is a termi-
>  nal, the standard output is appended to the file nohup.out in the current
>  directory.  If standard error is a terminal, it is directed to the same
>  place as the standard output.
>
>  Some shells may provide a builtin nohup command which is similar or iden-
>  tical to this utility.  Consult the builtin(1) manual page.
> ```

Bash's (*and other shells*) `&` will background the task. nohup with & effectively lets the process run in the background even whilst you terminate your tty/pty session.

I believe the problem is your Python program here is crashing. You should invest some time in some logging and find out. e.g:

```
nohup my_app.py &> myapp.log &
```